# Entity Relationship Diagram - 3 Tables that are not linked

Tags: sql, database, erd, entity-relationship

How do I go about making an ERD in which the 3 tables I have are not linked in any way, so there is not a foreign key amongst the tables?

- One table for registered users
- One table for storing events (e.g event name, location, time/date etc.)
- One table for image storing (for the gallery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have answer right into your question:

> 3 tables  are not linked in any way

So you just need to add desired entities on your ERD diagram and **no relations**. Your Entity Relationship Diagram will be *boring* and looks like:

[image]